# JanusGraph with Spark

Tags: maven, apache-spark, guava, janusgraph

I am trying to use JanusGraph 0.2.0 in our Spark program. Due to Guava version conflicts between Spark and JanusGraph, we were not able to proceed further.

As a workaround, we are trying to shade the guava artifact in JanusGraph and build it again.

Did any one tried doing this? If so, can you please provide some insight on how to do this.

Steps I did so far:

1. Shaded the guava artifact in janusgraph-core and built a fat jar.
2. Installed the janusgraph-core fat jar in local repository.
3. But when I tried to add the shaded janusgraph-core in janusgraph-hbase-parent POM, I am running into "Dependency convergence error".

Any idea on how to proceed further. If any of you had already built the JanusGraph with shaded Guava, can you please provide some insight.

Comment: Were you able to run spark with Janus in the end? Can you share sample code, please?

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the mistake: `janusgraph-hbase-parent` has `janusgraph-es` and `janusgraph-test` as dependencies, which, in turn, had `janus-core-0.2.0` as dependency which conflicted with `janus-core-0.2.0-shaded` [Shaded artifact].

Excluded `janus-core-0.2.0` from both test & es and it worked like a charm.